# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to add [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/availability-calendar-react) to my nextjs with ts but I get the next error :

```
Server Error

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
<unknown>
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CalendarTemplate from 'availability-calendar-react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const Page: React.FC = () => {
  const [availability, setAvailability] = useState([])
  const Calendar = CalendarTemplate({
    availability,
    setAvailability
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <Calendar />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

For reference I am using this [dashboard](https://github.com/ofekashery/react-dashboard-design)
I am getting the error when i refresh the page

Comment: @OMiShah same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `{}` braces from your import.

```
import {CalendarTemplate} from 'availability-calendar-react';
```

should be

```
import CalendarTemplate from 'availability-calendar-react';
```

This package uses a default export.

See https://blog.atomist.com/typescript-imports/ how imports work.

This probably does not fix all your issues but due to the lack of other files not provided it is hard to tell. `Cannot use import statement outside a module` is an error occuring when using ES module syntax in non modules. Load your script as module and it should work. See this for further instructions: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-module

Comment: Same thing after I remove

Comment: And I use the exactly same dashboard as I linked in the description, just edit one template files (like integrations.tsx) with my code and you have the exact code i have

Comment: So in the end I switched to a full js framework, but ty

Comment: To the first comment: That's what I said with `does not fix all your issues` ;). The error is still there because of server code is using commonjs but tries to use import statement like in es modules. Even this is in nextjs, it's still the same problem in your react app: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9890